# How do I change the attributes name for a validation failure message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried

```
validates :agree_tos, acceptance: {accept: true, message: ->(object, data) {'Terms of Service must be accepted.'}}, allow_nil: false, on: :update
```

but it says

> Agree tos Terms of Service must be accepted.

I also tried

```
validates :agree_tos, acceptance: {accept: true, message: 'Terms of Service'}, allow_nil: false, on: :update
```

[Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it in `/config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        agree_tos: "Terms of Service"
```

and used

```
validates :agree_tos, acceptance: true, allow_nil: false, on: :update
```

which yields

> Terms of Service must be accepted